# How do I send an ArrayList of User for parts SOAP?

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap

I have a database with many data users and have a method in SOAP to bring me back an ArrayList of all these users and list in a ListView in android, but the problem is what he tells me all data, if I have 1000 records in the bank, he will send me in 1000 if I have 10,000 he will send 10,000 and so on, this causes the error in the application and it takes too long to load all ... have any way to limit this request? him to send from 10 to 10 users and only when asked?

Here are my Object DAO

```
public ArrayList<Estudio> buscarTodosEstudios(){
    ArrayList<Estudio> lista = new ArrayList<Estudio>();

    try{
        Connection conn =  ConectaMySql.obtemConexao();

        String queryInserir = "SELECT * FROM estudios WHERE STATUS_ESTUDIO = 'ATIVO'";

        PreparedStatement ppStm = conn.prepareStatement(queryInserir);          



        ResultSet rSet = ppStm.executeQuery();

        while(rSet.next()){
            Estudio est = new Estudio();

            est.setID_ESTUDIO(rSet.getInt(1));
            est.setRAZAO_SOCIAL_ESTUDIO(rSet.getString(2));
            est.setNOME_FANTASIA_ESTUDIO(rSet.getString(3));
            est.setCNPJ_ESTUDIO(rSet.getString(4));
            est.setLOGO_ESTUDIO(rSet.getBytes(5));
            est.setSENHA_ESTUDIO(rSet.getString(6));
            est.setESTADO_ESTUDIO(rSet.getString(7));
            est.setCIDADE_ESTUDIO(rSet.getString(8));
            est.setBAIRRO_ESTUDIO(rSet.getString(9));
            est.setRUA_ESTUDIO(rSet.getString(10));
            est.setCEP_ESTUDIO(rSet.getString(11));
            est.setCOMPLEMENTO_ESTUDIO(rSet.getString(12));
            est.setTELEFONE_ESTUDIO(rSet.getString(13));
            est.setEMAIL_ESTUDIO(rSet.getString(14));
            est.setSITE_ESTUDIO(rSet.getString(15));
            est.setSALDO_ESTUDIO(rSet.getDouble(16));
            est.setSALDO_PENDENTE_ESTUDIO(rSet.getDouble(17));
            est.setSALDO_BLOQUEADO_ESTUDIO(rSet.getDouble(18));
            est.setCONTA_BANCARIA_ESTUDIO(rSet.getString(19));
            est.setSTATUS_ESTUDIO(rSet.getString(20));


            lista.add(est);
            }

        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return lista;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a limit in your queryInserir string, like so:

```
String queryInserir = "SELECT * FROM estudios WHERE STATUS_ESTUDIO = 'ATIVO' LIMIT yourLimit";
```

Comment: But how server will know that the application requested the first 10 users and want to call the next 10 starting from the previous count ?
Eg have 20 user registred in database , i push the first 10 , and now i need to push the 11 , 12, 13 ...